# VS hint gives build error

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to remove the little color marks in my Visual Studio code window by applying the VS hints, but these are apparentely impossible because these cause build errors. Here is my simplified code:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

XDocument XReport = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"));
XProcessingInstruction XI = ... ;//ref to xsl stylesheet
XReport.Add(XI);
XReport.Add(...more xml content...);
string NewPageContent = XReport.Declaration.ToString() + XReport.ToString();
```

Here is a screenshot when my mouse hovers over the wavy line under ToString:

[image: screenshot of the VS hints]

This code runs just fine, but VS hints that I should remove the `.ToString()` twice, then the code builds with an error that you cannot add an `XReport.Declaration` and an `XReport`, which makes sense.

Is this a known VS bug?

Any comments on making my code better is also appreciated.

Comment: I really don't see a good reason to remove the `.ToString()` if that is what you want. Are you sure VS is refering to the line you removed the `.ToString()` from? I don't get a warning on VS2013

Comment: What did the VS warning say exactly?

Comment: I added a screenshot. We agree that the `.ToString()` cannot be removed. What kind of bug is this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Visual Studio thing, it is a [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/CodeRush/refactor_pro.xml) add-in showing you this message.

The message is wrong, period. The `+` operator is invalid on those objects, and if they did implement the `+` operator, it would be unlikely to result in a `string`.

Report the bug at DevExpress.

Comment: You could be right. I have DevExpress controls installed. I inherited this pc and VS installation. So you mean that the programming hints with the wave lines and margin color marks are not made by VS, but by a DevExpress tool? I'll look into this.

Comment: Some of them indeed. The dialog is DE for sure, the lines are possibly Visual Studio's.

Comment: Here is my DevExpress question: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T171613

Comment: @Roland: Thanks. It might be useful to link to this post too. Anything more I can help with?

Comment: It will take a little longer to get a respons from DE than at this site ... but they are usually very helpful too

Answer (score 0):

Of course this not a bug but a feature :-)

We can remove either one of the `.ToString()` calls, but not both, and it will build ok! So the two hints are correct.

The new bug is that after removing one call, the other still has the wavy line, but cannot be removed.

I do not know the syntax details here, but if it builds, I guess it's ok.

(actually, I don't know if this qualifies as an answer)

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably a bug in an older version of DevExpress CodeRush. The current version might have fixed this. The DevExpress support team could not reproduce this error with the current version.